# jQuery - load html response into whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

In my ajax code, I get a html response. How can I replace the whole page to this html response? I only find `window.location.href`, which only can redirct url response.

My code:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/someurl',
        data: {'key': value},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(html_data) {
            # how to load this html_data into the whole page?
        },
        error: ...
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery `replaceWith` should get it done for you ;)

```
$( "html" ).replaceWith( data );
```

Where `data` is `html` received from server...

Entire code will look something like this...

```
$.get( "example.com/fileToLoad.html", function( data ) {
  $( "html" ).html( data );
});
```

Learn more about jQuery here...

http://jquery.com/

Comment: Hi, I just add my code on the question. I write $('html').replateWith(html_data), but get error: "jquery.js:5894 Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document-fragment' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'."

Comment: FIne, I just use $('html').html(html_data) to solve this problem. Thx!

Comment: better way thanx. but is there any way to open page with out replacing?

Answer (score 5):

window.document is an object containg whole DOM.

Try writing in console window.document and you will see whole structure of a page you're on. If you want only the body element then you can find it by tag and replace what's inside of it.

EDIT 1:

Actually you;re right. I didn't test it.

But you can do that by:

```
document.open();
document.write(your_html);
document.close();
```

Tested in console.

Comment: This method is the only one that will work if the data contains a <!DOCTYPE> and <html> element.